# Как реализовать кик из беседы вк на Bots Long Poll API?

Tags: python, python-3.x, вконтакте, python-3.5

Собственно вопрос в верху.. Хотелось бы пример кода чтоб понять как это делать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться библиотекой [`vk_api`](https://pypi.org/project/vk-api/) и методом [`messages.removeChatUser`](https://vk.com/dev/messages.removeChatUser).

***Пример:***

```py
from vk_api import VkApi

# Подставьте свои значения
ACCESS_TOKEN = ''  
CHAT_ID = ''
USER_ID = ''

vk = VkApi(token=ACCESS_TOKEN).get_api()
vk.messages.removeChatUser(
    chat_id=CHAT_ID,
    user_id=USER_ID,
)
```

Comment: Тоже не работает я все подставил исполнил код и ничего не произошло

Comment: @NNEETT34 Значит ошиблись в параметрах. Какой `chat_id` передавали? Обычно, это маленькое число (например, `3`). Больше `100000000` оно точно не будет.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно использовать метод [messages.removeChatUser](https://vk.com/dev/messages.removeChatUser):

```py
import requests

requests.get('https://api.vk.com/method/messages.removeChatUser?
chat_id=ID_БЕСЕДЫ&user_id=ID_ЧЕЛОВЕКА&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&v=5.122')
```

Только подставьте нужные значения

Comment: '{"error":{"error_code":100,"error_msg":"One of the parameters specified was missing or invalid: chat_id should be less than 100000000","request_params":[{"key":"chat_id","value":"2000000003"},{"key":"user_id","value":"560280419"},{"key":"v","value":"5.122"},{"key":"method","value":"messages.removeChatUser"},{"key":"oauth","value":"1"}]}}'

Comment: @NNEETT34 попробуй передавать не `2000000003` в chat_id, а просто `3`